# How to set visibility of Button in xaml Style ControlTemplate based on presence of DataGrid child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I have a Style declaration in xaml for a GroupBox.  This Style declaration includes a ControlTemplate that includes a Button.  I would like the Button visibility to be dependent on whether a DataGrid will be a child of the GroupBox.  The GroupBox is dynamically built in code-behind.

In the code-behind, a boolean value determines whether a DataGrid will be a child of the GroupBox at the time when the GroupBox is created.

I thought about using a boolean Attached Property (AP) for the GroupBox, that would specify whether a DataGrid would be the child of the GroupBox, but I'm not sure how this would be declared in the Style declaration (or if I would even declare an AP there), or how I could use the AP in the code-behind.

How do I set the Visibility property of the Button based on the presence of a DataGrid?

Could someone please give me a simple example of how I would set this up?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is with a DataTrigger, although you can also do it with  converter. Either way, you'll need to bind to that boolean value in your code behind. I'll assume you've set the window to be it's own DataContext, so just do something like this:

```
<Button Content="Press Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBooleanValue}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourBooleanValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, based on the additional info you've provided below I think I understand now what you're trying to do. Please correct me if any of this is wrong, but it sounds like you're creating GroupBox's an given some of them a DataGrid as a child:

```
        var groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
        this.thePanel.Children.Add(groupBox1);

        var groupBox2 = new GroupBox();
        var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Column1" });
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Column2" });
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Column3" });
        groupBox2.Content = dataGrid;
        this.thePanel.Children.Add(groupBox2);
```

Then in your style you have a ContentControl for GroupBoxes containing a button, and you only want that button to be visible on groupboxes that have a DataGrid for a child? If that's the case then you can do it easily enough with a converter. You bind the button's Visibility property to the GroupBox's content and then you use a converter to convert from that to a Visibility setting:

```
    <conv:ChildVisibilityConverter x:Key="ChildVisibilityConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5" Padding="5" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Group Box" />
                            <Button Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding Content, Converter={StaticResource ChildVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The actual converter itself simply looks at what it's been given (i.e. the GroupBox's Content), checks its type and returns the Visibility accordingly:

```
public class ChildVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        return (value.GetType() == typeof(DataGrid))
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So for that block of code I posted above you'll only see the button in the second GroupBox:

[image]

Does that answer the question?

Comment: Thanks Mark!! ... I have to create MANY of these GroupBoxes in the code-behind, and some may have a DataGrid child and others will not.  That's why I thought an attached property for the GroupBox would be useful (but I'm not sure that's the way to solve this).  Is the "YourBooleanValue" an attached property?

Comment: No, it's just a regular property, although it will have to support [property change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification) if you want visibility of the buttons to automatically change when you update it. To be honest you're making things a little bit hard for yourself doing things old-skool like this, MVVM was specifically designed to make tasks like this much easier.

Comment: Mark ... believe me when I tell you that I am a new employee to this code base and, in its present state, it leaves a lot to be desired.  A total rewrite of the code base is planned with MVVM being a big part of the re-do :-)  To be clear, the Button visibility needs to be set on a GroupBox by GroupBox basis.  That's why I thought of maybe using an Attached Property for the GroupBox, but I'm just not sure how to set it up.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @chuckp Answer updated, lemme know if I've misunderstood anything.

Comment: OMG!! ... I was trying to think of a GroupBox property to bind to for the Button visibility, and it didn't even cross my mind to just look at the Content property value which is set in the code-behind. Your solution works PERFECTLY!! Virtual adult beverage of your choice to you Mark!! Thank you SO much!!